# (mysql + sqlalchemy) check a str collation before insertion

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a user table which has a unique column 'nickname'.
the collation of this table is 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'.

I found that someone tried to set his/her nickname to '' which is utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE character.

and... an error occured.

```
'(MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1267, "Illegal mix '
                  'of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) and '
                  '(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation \'=\'") ...
```

I don't want to change user table collation or let someone have a nickname filled with emojis.
So... I want to make sure a user-input conforms to collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. how can I do that?

thank you in advance!

Comment: The database is already enforcing that for you. Just handle the exception and return a helpful message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

change your program database connection charset to utf8mb4,it seems like work well,but my program is php,you can try it yourself !

Comment: If that is a valid solution it should not be language dependant